# Purchasing tickets on United for someone else

Tags: air-travel, tickets, united-airlines

Some time ago I was trying to purchase flight tickets for someone else (from Eastern Europe to the US), to be specific, for 4 people at a time (I'm not among them), through the United website. I tried different itineraries (probably 3-4 itineraries), different browsers, different Internet connections. I had been trying for a week or so and I kept getting the following message (after entering credit card details and clicking "Pay"):

> Error
>
> We’re sorry, but united.com was unable to complete your request. Please try later or contact united.com Support in the U.S. and Canada at 1-800-396-1751; the U.K. at 0800 028 5003; elsewhere use the local phone number.

The card I was trying to use is a US-issued credit card, and to me it doesn't look like some fraud protection (from the bank) wouldn't allow me to book on United, because later I used it to book tickets for the same group of people on another airline's website.

According to the information found on different forums, people normally do not have trouble purchasing tickets for someone else online. I was wondering what was the problem in my case? For example, is United known to not allow purchasing tickets for someone else online if the flight does not originate in the US?

(I didn't call United, it was easier to just book tickets through a different airline, from a different alliance.)

Comment: I have several times booked United tickets for others, they are residing outside the US. No issues at all. i guess your problem has a different reason.

Comment: In which step you get such error? Sometime it is because of credit card used on the "wrong" country (because of laws [transparency of prices and consumer protection, you may see that you cannot use US sites with European credit card]. sometime it is just the credit card [fraud protection: you are using other names]. Try to contact them. Not enough information to answer.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I've added some details.